# Associate physical usb port to device

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, pyserial

I'm curently working on a testbench for some pcbs. They can be controlled though USB. I wrote some python code to send (using pySerial) orders to one card via the serial device "/dev/ttyACM0" The problem is that I need to test 5 cards at a time which means I need to differentiate  which card is controlled with “/dev/ttyACM*” and * depends on the pluging order (which I don’t control).

I used “usb-devices” command to have the name of each physical usb port but I need to send orders to these via pySerial. Is there a way to make that work?

Another solution I found is to use the “Dev:  n” number from “usb-devices” to communicate with “/dev/ttyn” but the permission to communicate through pySerial is denied, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in directory `/dev/serial/by-path/`. You should find a link to each tty eg `../../dev/ttyACM0`. The path should be stable. You can open these links just like `/dev/ttyACM0`.