# Identify which USB device is /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, serial-port, usbserial

I'm working with a Linux distribution (Raspbian) and I have two USB-Serial adapters which I'm connecting to the microcontroller. Whenever I connect both adapters, the serial ports "/dev/ttyUSB0" and "/dev/ttyUSB1" appear; here "/dev/ttyUSB0" is the adapter that was physically connected first (identified first by the system).

Now, I'm looking for a way to figure out which adapter is which in the event of a microcontroller restart. I.e., both adapters remained plugged into their USB ports and I can't physically unplug/replug to force which adapter is "USB0".

Basic research led me to these commands (pictures for reference):

`ls /dev/ttyUSB*` To list out the USB-serial ports that are active.

[image]

`lsusb` To get more information about the USB buses and connected devices.

[image]

Is there a way to relate these two results (or an alternative) to figure out what I need? For instance, in the pictures above "/dev/ttyUSB0" is "Bus 001 Device 008: ID 1a86:...", but how can I find that out through software (preferably using Python, but a shell script could work too)?

Comment: Both pieces of information are passed by udev to a hotplug script.  So you might read the udev (particularly, the "coldplug" portion) source code to see how it pairs them up.

Comment: To see that code in action try `udevinfo -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0` or `udevadm info --a --name /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Associate physical usb port to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779186/associate-physical-usb-port-to-device)

Comment: @BenVoigt Loos like the ```udevinfo``` command was updated to ```udevadm info```. This looks promising; do you know if there's something equivalent in python. If not, I think I'll try python's subprocess module to run that bash command from within my application.

Comment: @DanMicroS: I searched for "udevadm python" and found this: https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I actually managed to get it working through a subprocess but that python library already does that so I'll switch to that. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you want to do it from Python, `pyudev` has the following example code to access everything `udev` knows about a device identified by a device file:

```
from pyudev import Context, Device
context = Context()
device = Devices.from_device_file(context, '/dev/sda')
```

I believe that should work very nicely with `/dev/ttyUSB0` as well.

See https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyudev.html#pyudev.Devices.from_device_file

Once you have the device udev instance in Python, you can access `device.attributes` and `device.properties` to get a wealth of information including VID, PID, string descriptors, and so on.  The documentation says that

> all well-known dictionary methods and operators (e.g. `.keys()`, `.items()`, `in`) are available to access device properties.

Comment: I actually got it working using a subprocess and calling the bash command that way. But yes, I think using this designated python library is the better option in case of future improvements/modifications where I need more information. Thank You!

Comment: with pyudev version 0.22.0 you will get the following error: 'Devices' is not defined.

you can replace script above with -
''''
    import pyudev
    context = pyudev.Context()
    device = pyudev.Devices.from_device_file(context, '/dev/ttyUSB0')
''''

it works for me :)

Comment: It also works if you just add an s to the end of Device: from pyudev import Context, Devices

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that device.properties is a dict. My introspection foo is not so good and it took me ages to work that one out.

Comment: @Neil_UK: I think that's covered by the final quote?

Comment: @BenVoigt OK, my introspection foo is very, very bad, and I panic easily. Yes, coming back to it, of course that's what it implies. I think leaving my comment to stand doesn't harm the answer, and if it saves a noob some time, it's worth it.

Comment: @JasonC: The spelling `import Context, Device` with no `s` is exactly as it is in the documentation (link given).  It may be wrong, but if it is changed I can no longer claim to be citing the example from the package itself.